# Rally - clone existing app

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I'm trying to create a custom release burnup app for my group. There is an existing app called 'Release Burnup' in Rally, and based on the instructions for rally-app-builder I thought I would be able to clone this app as a starting point.

However, when I use the `rally-app-builder clone RallyApps ReleaseBurnup` command, it doesn't seem to do anything except change the title in the output html files to "*Son of* ReleaseBurnup". When I tried the same thing with the example from the github page (which uses `rally-app-builder clone RallyApps StoryBoard`) then it seems to be successfully cloning an app, with updates to the App.js file, etc.

I'm guessing that I might be using the wrong name to clone, but I'm not sure how to know what names are valid for this command to clone the app I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `rally-app-builder clone` functionality predates newer developments and the availability of source code of catalog apps from [RallyApps/app-catalog](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog), so it does not support drilling down those directories.

`clone RallyApps StoryBoard` works because there is a StoryBoard app at that location. There is no ReleaseBurnup there. ReleaseBurnup code is not available.

Here are the steps to build an app from javascript source files from GitHub app-catalog repository

- Prerequisites:

  [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

  [rally-app-builder](https://github.com/RallyApps/rally-app-builder)
- Get the source to a local directory (you may either fork the
  [app-catalog repo](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog), or download zip from the same location):
- in terminal, cd to the directory of the app you want to work on, and  call this command:

  `rally-app-builder build`.

As a result a deploy folder is created with App.html and
App-uncompressed.html inside, and App-debug.html is created in the
root folder of the app.

These steps make sense only if you intent to customize the catalog app and want to use the source as basis. If you want to use a catalog app as it was designed, install the app directly from the AppCatalog as described in [this help document](https://help.rallydev.com/use_apps).

Comment: Thanks! I also found the YouTube video series by David Thomas and I'm watching those to familiarize myself with the basics of Rally app development.

Comment: You are most welcome. Those videos are great, thank you for mentioning. Here is the link for the benefit of other readers: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3PQ-IsMxhG14aDViKxlPZASIrHatNkft I should also mention that rally-app-builder works only with AppSDK2, so it is not intended for the apps written with AppSDK1 available from the same RallyApps repo.