# Rally: IterationPlanningBoard

Tags: rally

Any idea where the iteration planning board app's color palette is coming from? I looked at the code but didn't find the source of the color palette. I was able to see it for EpicProgress report but not for IterationPlanningBoard in Rally.

Comment: @KyleMorse: Do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

The css file of IterationPlanningBoard is [here](https://github.com/RallySoftware/app-catalog/blob/master/src/apps/iterationplanningboard/IterationPlanningBoardApp.css), from the same 
[github repo](https://github.com/RallySoftware/app-catalog) where the source of Rally App Catalog apps is available.
If you want to customize a catalog app and generate new deployment html see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201406/rally-clone-existing-app).

Comment: but modifying the css won't help here as there is no css code for the color palette there. Looks like the css is coming from Rally in a file named `combined.css`